# Value is coming undefined first, then is coming alright, but still receive undefined on the page render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I managed to update a boolean value from the database, but I want to get the value now in the interface, so the user will see exactly the value from the database.

I did this using redux, so here it's my action:

```
export const getSettings = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CHANGE_SETTINGS_REQUEST, payload: {} });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(
      "http://localhost:3030/v1/lootbox/getSettings"
    );
    dispatch({ type: CHANGE_SETTINGS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    localStorage.setItem("changeSettingsInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CHANGE_SETTINGS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

In the component I have the following:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { changeSettings, getSettings } from "../../actions/adminActions";
import MessageBox from "../../components/ErrorBox/MessageBox";
import LoadingBox from "../../components/Spinner/LoadingBox";

export default function LootboxSettings() {
  const getSetting = useSelector((state) => state.getSetting);
  const { changeSettingsInfo, loading, error } = getSetting;
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(changeSettingsInfo?.isVisible);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCheck = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(changeSettings(checked));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSettings());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='login'>Lootbox Settings</div>
      {changeSettingsInfo && (
        <form className='swapping-currency-checkbox' onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          {loading && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
          {error && <MessageBox variant='danger'>{error}</MessageBox>}
          <label>Is lootbox visible?</label>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            className='swapping-currency-check'
            id='location'
            name='location'
            checked={checked}
            onChange={handleCheck}
            value='checkbox'
          />
          <div>
            <button className='buttonAccount swapping-btn' type='submit'>
              Save
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

So if I console.log changeSettingsInfo, I'm getting undefined and then the boolean value from the database(that's why I used the ? optional parameter), if i delete the optional I get an error, because it is undefined, here are the logs:

[image]

Something I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what, maybe on the useEffect. What can i do?

Comment: this is entirely expected behaviour. What is the actual problem?

Comment: The problem is that is not working, I don't know what you don't understand, the value should come true, not undefined, because is resulting in an error

Comment: I'm asking what the actual problem is - "it is not working" is not a sufficiently detailed problem statement to be able to debug. You already point out that you've used the ?. operator to avoid the page crashing, and that is perfectly fine, and means there's no longer a problem with the page crashing. So what is actually happening in your application that is different from what you want or expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to reflect change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(changeSettingsInfo?.isVisible);
}, [changeSettingsInfo]);
```

Explaination:

The UI is binded by a local state variable which is initialized when a component mounts.
The dispatch triggers a change on the store, whose values are passed as props to the functional component. Causing a re-render on the UI.
In your case your console still prints undefined for state variable `checked` because quite frankly on re-rendering of the component you are not setting the value for `checked`
So in order to do that, create a specialized useEffect that triggers whenever the value of your variable `changeSettingsInfo` changes.